# package adehabitatLT; command as.ltraj; duplicate elements

Tags: r

I am using the adehabitatLT R package to analise animal movements locations obtained through satellite trasmitters attached on animals. The dataset includes IdNumber, date, time, lat,long and other ancillary info. When i sort my data by IdNumber and date/time and manually check the results I cannot find any duplicate element. In R i read my csv file and create a dataframe using as.data.frame and by using the command duplicates() i find no duplicates whether i run the command on the whole dataframe or the date/time column/s, but when using the as.POSIXct() command i find 41 duplicates elements. My steps are:

```
required(adehabitatLT) #works fine

data<-read.csv("data....) #works fine

data<-as.data.frame(data) #works fine

duplicated(data) # works fine, no duplicates

duplicated(data$Date) #works fine, it finds duplicate dates as expected

duplicated(data$Time) #works fine, it finds duplicate times as expected

da <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(data$Date, data$Time), "%y%m%d %H:%M:%S"), tz="GMT") #works fine

sum(duplicated(da)) #returns 41 duplicate elements

trj<-as.ltraj(xy = data[,c("XD","YD")], date = da, id = data$IdNumber, typeII = TRUE)

Error in as.ltraj(xy = satdat[, c("XD", "YD")], date = da, id = satdat$IdNumber,  : 
  non unique dates for a given burst
```

I expect the error message given the fact that there are duplicate elements in da (2 or more different IdNumbers can have the same date/time for a same/different position), but i guessed that when the da element is associated to the IdNumber and the lat and long coordinates, all the rows should be unique (as for the manually checked data, i am 100% sure that there are no duplicates).

What am I missing, doing wrong?

P.S.: the command as.jtraj for typeI trajectories works of course fine

---

Update1:

This is the structure of my dataframe called "satdat"

```
    PPT   Date     Time              DT       XD       YD     XUTM    YUTM
1 87776 150314 17:46:24 150314 17.46.24 35.57666 12.33740 780225.6 1365210
2 87776 150314 19:22:29 150314 19.22.29 35.58675 12.34696 781313.4 1366279
3 87776 150314 20:14:00 150314 20.14.00 35.60735 12.34675 783555.3 1366277
4 87776 150314 21:06:28 150314 21.06.28 35.60846 12.35585 783666.3 1367286
5 87776 150314 21:57:37 150314 21.57.37 35.61608 12.36045 784490.5 1367803
6 87776 150315 02:04:36 150315 02.04.36 35.54072 12.41002 776238.2 1373210

sum(duplicated(satdat)) #check for duplicate

[1] 0

da <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(satdat$Date, satdat$Time), "%y%m%d %H:%M:%S"), tz="GMT") #create successfully my POSIXct element

head(da)

[1] "2015-03-14 17:46:24 GMT" "2015-03-14 19:22:29 GMT" "2015-03-14 20:14:00 GMT" "2015-03-14 21:06:28 GMT" "2015-03-14 21:57:37 GMT"
[6] "2015-03-15 02:04:36 GMT"

sum(duplicated(da)) #check for duplicates; i expect duplicates

[1] 44

duplicated(da) #which are duplicated? apparently the element number 14
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

satdat[14,]

     PPT   Date     Time              DT       XD       YD     XUTM    YUTM
14 87776 150315 16:17:17 150315 16.17.17 35.58955 12.41916 781540.6 1374273
```

Weird, there are no other rows with the same values, manually checked.

Comment: Can you show some example that reproduce the error

Comment: Do you mean examples of data? Here it follows:

Comment: Yes, please do update in your post so that it becomes easier for others to test.

Comment: What is the output for `subset(satdat,satdat$Date == "150315" & satdat$Time == "16:17:17")` ? Your 14th date is a duplicate of another earlier date, but as we have incomplete datas here we have to guess... (but the subset command should show you the rows with the same timestamp)

Comment: after subsetting i have 2 records with same PPT number date, time but different lat/long:

subset(satdat,satdat$Date == "150315" & satdat$Time == "16:17:17")
     PPT   Date     Time              DT       XD       YD     XUTM    YUTM
13 87776 150315 16:17:17 150315 16.17.17 35.57586 12.42854 780041.2 1375297
14 87776 150315 16:17:17 150315 16.17.17 35.58955 12.41916 781540.6 1374273